# HDInsight client missing lib

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

We have HDinsight cluster running on Azure. I was trying to create a client machine to connect to HDInsight. I followed the instruction from Hortonworks installation guide to install all client component, and then copied /etc/hadoop/conf from one of the HDInsight node to this new node. But when I try to access the cluster by hadoop fs -ls I get following error

```
root@sbd-docker:~# hadoop fs -ls /
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [com.microsoft.log4jappender.EtwAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.log4jappender.EtwAppender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:790)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.<clinit>(FsShell.java:43)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "ETW".
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [com.microsoft.log4jappender.FilterLogAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.log4jappender.FilterLogAppender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:790)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.<clinit>(FsShell.java:43)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "FilterLog".
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [com.microsoft.log4jappender.EtwAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.log4jappender.EtwAppender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:790)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.<clinit>(FsShell.java:43)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "ETW".
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [com.microsoft.log4jappender.FilterLogAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.log4jappender.FilterLogAppender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:790)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.<clinit>(FsShell.java:43)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "AMFilterLog".
16/06/23 16:57:20 WARN impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Error creating sink 'azurefs2'
org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfigException: Error creating plugin: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.WasbAzureIaasSink
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig.getPlugin(MetricsConfig.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.newSink(MetricsSystemImpl.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configureSinks(MetricsSystemImpl.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configure(MetricsSystemImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.start(MetricsSystemImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.init(MetricsSystemImpl.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.metrics.AzureFileSystemMetricsSystem.fileSystemStarted(AzureFileSystemMetricsSystem.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.WasbAzureIaasSink
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig.getPlugin(MetricsConfig.java:196)
    ... 24 more
ls: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.KeyProviderException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common/decrypt.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I don't know which package is missing here, can anyone help here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then copied /etc/hadoop/conf from one of the HDInsight node
>   ...
>
> ```
> ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.log4jappender.EtwAppender
> ```

This indicates you copied the log configuration and the HDInsight appears to have a Microsoft specific [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) extension using [ETW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx). Do you want/need this logging? If yes, you need to make sure you copy the relevant JARs from the HDInsight libs. If not, change the node logging configuration not to use this class.

Comment: I removed ETW reference, but still gets 
ls: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.KeyProviderException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common/decrypt.sh": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: Any idea which package install `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need [microsoft-log4j-etwappender-1.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2/1.0.10)